# Can't set @model to class in dynamic loaded dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-assembly

I'm working on a MVC project where we dynamically load dll's. In these dll's are other MVC projects (we call them modules). We do this so we can support a plug-and-play for the modules, update them without publishing the whole project.

We have multiple simple modules that work, now I'm facing a problem with a new module I'm developing.

In all the view of the module we define the model like `@model dynamic`. But because I want to use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` that´s not allowed else it results in

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

So I thought, no problem I'll just change to `@model ModuleNameSpace.ClassName` But now the whole view can´t be loaded anymore... exception says:

> The view found at '~/PATH_TO_VIEW_FILE' was not created.

With `@model dynamic` the view is working and when I create a seperate project it's also working with `@model ModuleNameSpace.ClassName`. So it seems to be a problem because we add the assembly dynamical?

Modules are loaded like this:

```
System.Reflection.AssemblyName name = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(module.FullName);
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. The problem was that the model didn't find the class in the assembly. I don't know exactly why but I've found a way to solve it.

You're able to set a function for the case an assembly is not found. Because I trust the source and this is an internal application I can set full trust in the web config. In the resolve method I point to the dll's where the module is in and then the class is found and it works!

Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
  {
             AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

             currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

 }

 static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
 {
             var pluginsFolder = GetPluginFolder()
         return (from f in pluginsFolder.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     let assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(f.FullName)
                     where assemblyName.FullName == args.Name || assemblyName.FullName.Split(',')[0] == args.Name
                     select Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName)).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Thanks to [shawazza](https://shazwazza.com/post/Developing-a-plugin-framework-in-ASPNET-with-medium-trust)